# PowerShell: Incremental Counter in Foreach Loop

Tags: powershell

I have a foreach loop that iterates over an Array and calls a function which also has another foreach loop inside with an incremental counter, however it doesn't seem to be working as expected?

Array contents:

```
| Username | Username2 |
|----------|-----------|
| p1       | p2        |
| p3       | p4        |
```

Code:

```
function insertIntoLunchJobs($arrayOfRows) {
    $counter = 1

    foreach ($i in $arrayOfRows) {
        $i
        $counter++
        $counter
    }
}
```

Output:

```
| Username | Username2 |
|----------|-----------|
| p1       | p2        |
| 2        |           |
| p3       | p4        |
| 2        |           |
```

Desired result:

```
| Username | Username2 |
|----------|-----------|
| p1       | p2        |
| 2        |           |
| p3       | p4        |
| 3        |           |
```

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: You want to do a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamZinala do you know how I can construct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm literally copy pasting your code. I don't see any errors here:

```
$arr=@'
Username,Username2
p1,p2
p3,p4
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv

function insertIntoLunchJobs($arrayOfRows) {
    $counter = 1

    foreach ($i in $arrayOfRows) {
        $i
        $counter++
        $counter
    }
}

insertIntoLunchJobs -arrayOfRows $arr
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate, I actually logically had an issue. Basically I did a foreach loop over $arr and then called the insertIntoLunchJobs function. Thanks for your help